# Indentation with "paracol" on multi-line text?

Tags: indentation, paracol

So, I'm using the [paracol-package](http://ctan.localhost.net.ar/macros/latex/contrib/paracol/paracol-man.pdf). I would like to ask if it were possible to have an automatic indentation at the breaks of "long" (i.e. multi-line) texts.

Consider, e.g. a paracol with 2 columns, called for via

```
\columnratio{0.5, 0.5}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\raggedright
...
\end{paracol}
```

As for now, this gives the following (without indentation on multi-line text):

[image]

However, my question is: is it possible, with [paracol](http://ctan.localhost.net.ar/macros/latex/contrib/paracol/paracol-man.pdf), to receive the following (with automatic indentation):

[image]

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can try the following:

```
\everypar{\hangindent1cm\hangafter1}
```

Assuming that the indentation is required for all the paragraphs!

Comment: +1 Even `\everypar{\hangindent1cm}`  is enough.

Comment: At first, this wasn't working. In my case, there seemed to be some inhibition of your code, when also using `\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{2cm}` 
`... FOO ...` `\end{adjustwidth}`. I don't understand why this was interfering ... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a negative `\parindent` and a positive `\leftskip`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol,xparse,indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{hangparacol}{mo}
  {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\begin{paracol}{#1}}{\begin{paracol}{#1}[#2]}%
   \raggedright
   \parindent=-3em \leftskip=3em}
  {\end{paracol}}

\columnratio{0.5, 0.5}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{hangparacol}{2}[\section{Title}]
\lipsum[1-2]

\switchcolumn

\lipsum[3-4]
\end{hangparacol}

\end{document}
```

I used the optional argument just to show it works (but `indentfirst` becomes necessary in this case).

[image]

Comment: Works exquisite as well! You are very thanked for your elaborate answer of high pedagogical value.